# Behaviour of a function related to prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let the second Chebyshev function : $$\psi(x)=\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n) \\ V(\xi)=e^{-\xi}\psi(e^{\xi})-1 \\ \alpha=\limsup_{\xi\to+\infty}|V(\xi)|$$
I already derived there exist $A\ge0$ such that for all $\xi_1,\xi_2\ge0$ :
$$\Biggl|\int_{\xi_1}^{\xi_2}V(\eta)d\eta\Biggl|\lt A$$
Suppose $\alpha\gt0$ and let $$\delta=\frac{3\alpha^2+4A}{2\alpha}\gt \alpha$$
The function $V$ decreases except at its discontinuities where it increases.
I'm having trouble establishing this statement :

For all $\zeta\ge 0 $ we have :

Case 1 :

$$\exists\eta_0 \in[\zeta,\zeta+\delta-\alpha] ,V(\eta_0)=0$$

Case 2 :

For all $\eta\in[\zeta,\zeta+\delta-\alpha]$ $V(\eta)$ changes sign at most once.

Could someone help me please ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what results on $\zeta,\psi$ you are assuming. Also why do you want to estimate the number of sign changes ? It is much harder than the PNT which is $e^{-x}\psi(e^x) -1 \to 0$

Comment: http://plouffe.fr/simon/Phys%20et%20Math/Hardy%20and%20Wright%20Theory%20of%20Numbers.pdf p-366 could help

Comment: It is about Selberg elementary proof of the PNT https://www.math.lsu.edu/~mahlburg/teaching/handouts/2014-7230/Selberg-ElemPNT1949.pdf there are plenty of discussions about why it is more complicated than the complex analysis tauberian proof and why discussing the details isn't really useful.

Comment: I didn't see any discussion about this part of the proof.

Comment: Which part of the proof ? You didn't provide any context which doesn't make sense when it is about proving the PNT.

Comment: Page 366 of the book I linked.